# Change SurfaceScrollViewer Style

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make the SurfaceScrollViewer use Black thumbs instead of white. I have not found anything explaining how to do this, I have managed to change the Color of the Scrollbars itself, but the Thumbs are always white.

How can I change the color of the SurfaceScrollViewer thumbs?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a wpf usercontrol with "SurfaceScrollViewer" you could right click on your scrollviewer (in the design view) -> edit a template -> edit a copy and change the thumbs in the template.

Comment: Yes I managed to do it, the thumbs was hidden waaay down the template, I had to go trough many templates. Probably I did not see this because I am not very familiar with WPF yet. The SurfaceScrollViewer is part of the Surface SDK of Microsoft

Comment: Yep... editing the templates can be a bit challenging ;)